# 3 variable multiplication with 1 constraint lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Using Lagrange multipliers, I need to calculate all points $(x,y,z)$ such that $$x^4y^6z^2$$ has a maximum or a minimum subject to the constraint that $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$$

So, $f(x,y,z) = x^4y^6z^2 $

and $g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1$

then i've done the partial derivatives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=\lambda\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$$

which gives

$$4x^3y^6z^2 = 2xλ$$

$$6x^4y^5z^2 = 2yλ$$

$$2x^4y^6z = 2zλ$$

which i subsequently go on to find that

$3x^2 = 2y^2 = 6z^2 $

This is where i've hit a dead end. Where do i go from here? or am i doing it all wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: On this site, it is advisable you format your question using mathjax (for a tutorial, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ). I edited your question this time, but in future, please format it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now express $y^2$ and $z^2$ as functions of $x$ -- for example, $y^2=\frac32 x^2$.

Then, use the last equation you didn't use yet, which is

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

and plug in $y^2$ and $z^2$. You should get one single equation for $x$.

Comment: Thanks, resulted in me getting x = 1/sqrt(3) , y = 1/sqrt(2) and z = 1/sqrt(6) which then led me to getting the result in the other solution provided. I'm not allowed a calculator so i left it as is however.

Comment: @Obit11 Again, please, use Mathjax. Do you not think $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is much easier to read than 1/sqrt(3)? Also, you should rationalize, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Comment: okay thanks. sorry for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal value is $0$ for $x=0$.

The maximal value we can find by AM-GM:
$$x^4y^6z^2=108\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{y^2}{3}\right)^3z^2\leq108\left(\frac{2\cdot\frac{x^2}{2}+3\cdot\frac{y^2}{3}+z^2}{6}\right)^6=\frac{1}{432}.$$
The equality occurs for $\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{y^2}{3}=z^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$,

which says that $\frac{1}{432}$ is a maximal value.

Done!

If you wish to use the Lagrange multipliers method you need to add the following words.

Let $F(x,y,z,\lambda)=x^4y^6z^2+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ and $A=\left\{(x,y,z,\lambda)|x^2+y^2+z^2=1\right\}$.

Sinse $F$ is a continuous function and $A$ is a compact, we see that $F$ gets on $A$ the maximal value and gets on $A$ the minimal value, which happens for solutions of your system.

The rest is to solve the system $\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{y^2}{3}=z^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ for $xyz\neq0$ and to solve your system for $xyz=0$.

Now, you can choose, that you want.

I think that to solve our problem by AM-GM is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Lagrange multipliers, also called Lagrangian multipliers (e.g., Arfken 1985, p. 945), can be used to find the extrema of a multivariate function  subject to the constraint , where  and  are functions with continuous first partial derivatives on the open set containing the curve , and  at any point on the curve (where  is the gradient).

For an extremum of  to exist on , the gradient of  must line up with the gradient of . In the illustration above,  is shown in red,  in blue, and the intersection of  and  is indicated in light blue. The gradient is a horizontal vector (i.e., it has no -component) that shows the direction that the function increases; for  it is perpendicular to the curve, which is a straight line in this case. If the two gradients are in the same direction, then one is a multiple () of the other, so

(1)

The two vectors are equal, so all of their components are as well, giving

(2)

for all , ..., , where the constant  is called the Lagrange multiplier.

The extremum is then found by solving the  equations in  unknowns, which is done without inverting , which is why Lagrange multipliers can be so useful.

For multiple constraints , , ...,

To minimize a simple non-linear function by using Lagrange Multipliers.

EQUATION GIVEN :
5 - (x-2)^(2 )  - 2⋅(y-1)^2
x + 4y = 3

Consider the as f(x,y) and λ(x,y)

f(x,y)  =  5 - (x-2)^(2 )  - 2⋅(y-1)^2
λ(x,y)  = x + 4y – 3

Adding equation

g(x,y) = f(x,y) + λ(x,y)

∂g/∂x  = 0

∂g/∂y  = 0

∂g/∂λ  = 0

Taking derivative with respect to x

∂g/∂x  =  (∂(f(x,y) + λ(x,y)))/∂x

∂g/∂x  =  (∂(5 - (x-2)^(2 )  - 2⋅(y-1)^2  + x + 4y - 3))/∂x

∂g/∂x =    -2x + 4 + λ ……. [1]

Taking derivative with respect to y

∂g/∂y  =  (∂(f(x,y) + λ(x,y)))/∂y

∂g/∂y  =  (∂(5 - (x-2)^(2 )  - 2⋅(y-1)^2  + x + 4y - 3))/∂y

∂g/∂y =   - 4y + 4 + 4λ

λ = y-1 ..........[2]

Taking derivative with respect to λ

∂g/(∂λ )  =  (∂(f(x,y) + λ(x,y)))/(∂λ )

∂g/(∂λ )  =  (∂(5 - (x-2)^(2 )  - 2⋅(y-1)^2  + x + 4y - 3))/(∂λ )
∂g/(∂λ ) =   x + 4y - 3 ……[3]

Multiply [2] by 3, we get

9y - 3 = 0
y =  1/(3 )………[4]

Put the value of y in eq. [1], we get

λ = (1/(3 ) - 1)

λ  = (-2)/(3 )………. [5]

Put the value of y in eq. [3], we get

x + 4(1/3) - 3 = 0

x = -4(1/3) + 3

x =  5/3………. [6]

f(x,y)  =  5 - (x-2)^(2 )  - 2⋅(y-1)^2

f(x,y)  =  5 - (5/3-2)^(2 )  - 2⋅(1/(3 )-1)^2

f(x,y) = 4
    Value of Constraint minimization is 4